# Is there a truly multiplatform testing setup for Jetbrains @Composable functions?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-android-extensions, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I'd love to be able to get a `@Composable` context running in the `androidTest` target of my common project, in order to test higher-order components that reside in `commonMain`, such as ContentLocalProviders and layouts.  Something like:

```
@Test fun testSomethingComposable() = runComposeTest {
    @Composable fun <M> buildMutableState(model: M) { /* ... */ }

    assertNotNull { buildMutableState(initialState).value }
}
```

I began with `expect fun runComposeTest(content: @Composable ()->Unit)` inside of `commonTest`, but only the `jvmTest` version works.  The `createComposeRule().setContent {}` function offered by AndroidX only works within an instrumented test.

Any other way around this?  Meanwhile, I've just pushed my tests down to `jvmTest` so that I can move forward.

The `jvmTest` version:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application
actual fun runComposeTest(content: @Composable () -> Unit) = runTest {
    application(false) {content}
}
```

But the following fails in `androidTest`:

```kotlin
actual fun runComposeTest(content: @Composable () -> Unit) = runTest {
    val rule = createComposeRule()
    rule.setContent(content)
}
```

... For somewhat obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they have a test framework  that to my knowledge hasn't been announced and receives no mention in the documentation.  I added a [gist with the full build.gradle.kts](https://gist.github.com/tylergannon/9d88c621abb0607bbe86882b2de6bfb2).

But basically, you're looking to add `org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4` to your project.  I'm running on alpha software so that's:

```
kotlin { sourceSets {
  val commonTest {
    dependencies {
      /* ... */
      implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
      implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
      implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.2.0-alpha01-dev620")
    }
  }
  val jvmMain by getting {
    dependencies {
      /**
       * Note this is needed for tests to run.
       **/
      implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    }
  }
  val jvmTest by getting {
    dependencies {
      implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    }
  }
}
```

These tests currently don't work under JUnit5, or so I read somewhere (sorry no reference).  Therefore note the explicit `kotlin("test-junit")`
instead of `"test"`, which will load junit5.